# Bug in toolbar android keyboard appear in v1.framework7

Tags: android, webview, html-framework-7

when android keyboard is appear then toolbar and navbar cover the screen.
Actually i want when keyboard appear then toolbar hide and when keyboard hide then toolbar show

Please check screenshot
https://prnt.sc/j3npos 
https://prnt.sc/j3npwe

and I want 
https://prnt.sc/j3ns4k

Comment: @Vodet I am asking for framework7 with webview like hybrid app not for any ListView or native app

Comment: you can hide toolbar from script when keyboard event is triggered.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy you are right we need to execute script when keyboard event is triggered but can you suggest me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution

```
myApp.onPageInit('*', function (page) {

        $(document).on('focus', 'input, textarea', function(){
            $(".toolbar,.overTripBottom").addClass("hide")
            //alert("yes")
        });

        $(document).on('blur', 'input, textarea', function(){
            $(".toolbar,.overTripBottom").removeClass("hide")
            //alert("yes on")
        });
}
```

this work for me